# Avoiding explicit casts in Factory

Tags: scala, types, casting, factory

I have an external DSL (Combinator-Parsers) to define `Extractor[A]` where A is the type that is extracted when the Extractor has been executed.

An extractor consists of steps that call the next step as the continuation.
The extractor creates intermediate extractions (string-based key/value-pairs), which are finally transformed into the proper `A`s by a factory.

Extractor: `case class Extractor[A](id: String, start: Step[A], factory: Factory[A])`

Step: `sealed trait Step[A] {
  def process(ctx: Context[A]): List[A]
}`

Factory: `trait Factory[A] { def create(extracts: List[(String,String)]): List[A] }`

Currently my extractor-parser looks like the following:

```
  val extractor: Parser[Extractor[_]] = trace ~ "EXTRACT" ~ extractorType ~ extractorId ~ step ^^ {
    case t ~ _ ~ ty ~ id ~ step => {
      val extr = ty match {
        case "SUBTITLES" => {
          Extractor[MovieInfos.Subtitle](id, step.asInstanceOf[Step[MovieInfos.Subtitle]], new SubtitleFactory)
        }
        case x => throw new InvalidExtractorType(x)
      }
      extr.trace(t)
    }
  }
```

**EDIT**: The step-parser has signature `val step: Parser[Step[_]]` (the step-parser is not able to know that type of `Step[A]` it is exactly parsing. Finally the step gets its proper `A`-type by the extractor-parser's `asInstanceOf`)

The above extractor parser is currently only able to parse extractors of extractorType `"SUBTITLES"`. I want to add other extractorTypes successively, e.g. `case "REVIEWS" => ...`.

For each extractor `Extractor[A]`, I have to provide a specialized factory (e.g. `new SubtitleFactory`) that creates things of type `A` (e.g. `MovieInfos.Subtitle`) and pass matching `step`s into the extractor (that's what the `asInstanceOf` is for).

The parser has to parse different Extractor-Types (Subtitles, Images, Audiotracks, etc.),
so I use `Parser[Extractor[_]]`, is this properly typed or is there any better way?

Furthermore, I want to avoid that `step.asInstanceOf[Step[MovieInfos.Subtitle]]` which looks a bit fishy since I already provided the proper type `Extractor[MovieInfos.Subtitle]`

And finally I want a more flexible Factory, possibly extensible by some sort of configuration/hooks.

Any recommendations appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Maybe try `def extractor[T]: Parser[Extractor[T]] = ...`

Comment: I do not know the type of the resulting extractor when calling the parser.

Comment: ...  ~ (step: Step[MovieInfos.Subtitle]) => ...

Comment: perhaps you provide some more code such that we can understand better.

Comment: Not enough information. Why do you need the `asInstanceOf`? We can't tell, because you neither explain what happens when you leave it off, not provide the type signature of `Extractor` and `step` (or any of the other grammar pieces).